# How to use regex capture groups in pandas replace function

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I've got a pandas DataFrame that uses "2Nd" instead of "2nd", "136Th" instead of "136th", etc. I want the letter immediately following the number to be lowercase.

Sample data:

```
data = pd.Series(['21St StNew York', 'Exampe BlvdSt Louis', '1St Rd'])
```

Desired output:

```
['21st StNew York', 'Exampe BlvdSt Louis', '1st Rd']
```

Tried using `str.replace()`:

```
data = data.str.replace('\BSt', 'st', regex=True)
['21st StNew York', 'Exampe Blvdst Louis', '1st Rd']
```

Is it possible to use a capture group?

```
data = data.str.replace('[0-9]+(St)', 'st', regex=True)
['st StNew York', 'Exampe BlvdSt Louis', 'st Rd']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a callable for `repl`

```
new_data = data.str.replace('(\d+[A-Z])', lambda m: m.group(1).lower())

Out[49]:
0        21st StNew York
1    Exampe BlvdSt Louis
2                 1st Rd
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try doing a regex replacement on the pattern `(?<=\d)[A-Z]`, and then replacing with the lowercase version:

```
df['dat'] = df['data'].str.replace(r'(?<=\d)[A-Z]', lambda x: x.group(0).lower())
```

Comment: This is returning null values for me for some reason.